# java rounding to two decimals

Tags: java

I have a number

```
double num = 1.234567;
```

and I'm trying to keep only two decimals

```
num = (int)((num * 100) + 0.5) / 100.0;
```

but the actual number I got is 1.230000000001. How can I get rid of the 0000000001 part?

Comment: u sure with casting it to int u r getting 1.2300...1? I am getting the answer as 1.23 .. however if i dont cast it , I get 1.239567

Comment: yes, i got a bunch of zeros and cannot solve the problem

Comment: might be there would be difference in OS - mine is 64 bit MAC-OS .. anyways whats the range of values of num ?

Comment: I'm running debian 64 bit... I don't know the range

Comment: i meant .. what can be the range of value of num you are expecting (test case)

Answer (score 2):

Try [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
DecimalFormat twoDp= new DecimalFormat("#.##");
Double.valueOf(twoDp.format(num));
```

Comment: try this :  MathContext mc= new MathContext(3) ;//Precision
    BigDecimal b =new BigDecimal(num,mc);
    System.out.println(b.doubleValue());

Comment: @user1428716 No answer that converts the value back to floating point can possibly be correct. FP doesn't have decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, unless you switch to a decimal radix. Doubles and floats don't have decimal places, they have binary places, so you can't round or truncate them to specific numbers of decimal places except in the cases where the value representations are congruent, i.e. the negative powers of 2.

So you have to either use `DecimalFormat` if you are presenting the result, or `BigDecimal` if you want to keep computing with it.

Any solution that ends by turning the value back into floating point is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

```
String result = String.format("%.2f", num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. this should solve it

```
       Double num = //value
   num = //arithmetic


   String temp =num.toString().split("\\.")[0];
       int precision=temp.length();
       BigDecimal b =new BigDecimal(num,new MathContext(precision+2));
   System.out.println(b.doubleValue());
```